# Python usando tkinter Figura encima de otra

Tags: python, tkinter

Hola soy nuevo en esta página y programando, tengo un proyecto en donde debo hacer un programa de recolección de burbujas ya sea círculos o imágenes de estas, donde debo dar click y que este genere una figura fractal por cada click.

El fractal se tiene que generar a partir de una distancia en la que este no se genere encima de la figura anterior, osea el fractal, y que la distancia a la que se puede hacer click y generarlo no quede tan lejos. Cuando comienza el programa se generan estas burbujas y se genera el fractal en la parte inferior de la pantalla , al hacer click crea una línea de figuras hasta llegar a una burbuja, y si la figura toca la burbuja esta desaparece y se comienzan a sumar los puntos. Estas figuras desaparecen y regresan a la posición original al recolectar las burbujas que quedan y asi es como funciona todo este juego.

Con esto genero las burbujas:

```
from tkinter import  *
import random

ventana = Tk ()
ventana.title ("Ventana")

label1 = Label (ventana,text=" Jugador 1 ")
label1.grid()
label1  =  Label (ventana,text ="Puntuacion:  ")
label1.grid()

canvas=Canvas (ventana, width=1500, height=900, borderwidth=0,
               highlightthickness=0, bg= "orange")
canvas.grid()


def _create_circle (self, x, y, r, **kwargs):
    return self.create_oval (x-r, y-r, x+r, y+r, **kwargs)

Canvas.create_circle = _create_circle

colores=["red", "blue", "orange", "yellow", "purple", "green",  "black", 
"white", "#5E00FF"]

for i in range (0,10):        
      n= random.randint (10,1000)         
      n2 = random.randint (20,700)          
      canvas.create_circle (n,  n2,  20,  fill=colores [1])

ventana.mainloop ()
```

Necesito ayuda para que no vaya quedando una encima de otra, ese es mi problema ahora, por favor ayúdenme y de antemano gracias,

Answer (score 1):

La forma más común de solventar este problema es comprobar si las circunferencias se solapan. Para ver si dos circunferencias se solapan basta con conocer su radio y su centro (que es lo que usas para crearlas). Teniendo esto, basta con calcular la distancia entre ambas, que no es más que el cálculo de la hipotenusa de un triángulo rectángulo (Teorema de Pitágoras):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con lo que la fórmula para calcular la distancia es:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Teniendo lo anterior en cuenta basta con crear una funcíón en Python que retorne si dos circunferencias se solapan o no y por cada nueva circunferencia creada aleatoriamente comprobamos si se solapa con alguna de las esxistentes. Para ello guardamos cada circunferencia en un conjunto (`set`) como una tupla de la forma `(x, y, radio)` y nos valemos de `any` para hacer la comprobación por cada círculo nuevo a crear. Podemos, además, añadir una tercera condición para que los nuevos circulos no solo no se solapen, sino que estén a una determinada distancia mínima del resto:

```
def solapamiento(cir1, cir2, esp = 0):
    # cir1 y cir2 son tuplas de la forma (x, y, radio)
    # esp es la separación mínima que ha de haber entre circunferencias
    distancia = ((cir2[0] - cir1[0])**2 + (cir2[1] - cir1[1])**2)**0.5
    return (cir1[2] + cir2[2] + esp) > abs(distancia)


circulos = set()
espaciamiento = 10
n = 10
while len(circulos) < n:
    x= random.randint (10,1000)         
    y = random.randint (20,700)
    r = 20
    cir = (x, y, r)
    if not any(solapamiento(cir, c, espaciamiento) for c in circulos):
        circulos.add(cir)
```

Lógicamente, hay que tener cuidado con los parámetros. A mayor radio o mayor separación menos círculos se pueden crear y más difícil es que `random` de con un círculo aceptado. Se puede adaptar el `while` para que si no encuentra todos los círculos en `i` iteraciones se salga y dibuje los que tenga, evitando que si le pedimos que cree más círculos de los posibles por el espacio disponible se quede iterando de forma infinita.

Tu código quedaría así:

```
import random
import tkinter as tk

class MyCanvas(tk.Canvas):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Canvas.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)

    def create_circle (self, x, y, r, **kwargs):
        return self.create_oval (x-r, y-r, x+r, y+r, **kwargs)

colores=["red", "blue", "yellow", "purple", "green",  "black", 
"white", "#5E00FF"]

ventana = tk.Tk ()
ventana.title ("Ventana")

label1 = tk.Label (ventana,text=" Jugador 1 ")
label1.grid()
label1  =  tk.Label (ventana,text ="Puntuacion:  ")
label1.grid()

canvas = MyCanvas(ventana, width=1500, height=900, borderwidth=0,
                  highlightthickness=0, bg= "orange")
canvas.grid()

def solapamiento(cir1, cir2, esp = 0):
    # cir1 y cir2 son tuplas de la forma (x, y, radio)
    # esp es la separación mínima que ha de haber entre circunsferencias
    distancia = ((cir2[0] - cir1[0])**2 + (cir2[1] - cir1[1])**2)**0.5
    return (cir1[2] + cir2[2] + esp) > abs(distancia)


circulos = set()
espaciamiento = 10
n = 10
while len(circulos) < n:
    x= random.randint(10,1000)         
    y = random.randint(20,700)
    r = random.randint(15,40)
    color = random.choice(colores)
    cir = (x, y, r)
    if not any(solapamiento(cir, c, espaciamiento) for c in circulos):
        circulos.add(cir)
        canvas.create_circle (x,  y,  r,  fill = color)

ventana.mainloop ()
```

He modificado algunas cosas, además de lo anterior:

- No debes usar la forma de importar `from módulo import *` en Python. Es una mala práctica, peligroso en códigos complejos y extensos, muy ineficiente con la memoria y dificulta la lectura por terceros. Recuerda el zen de Python: "Explícito mejor que implícito". La forma común es usar `import tkinter as tk`, también puedes usar `import tkinter` o `from tkinter import Canvas, Label, ...`.
- La forma en la que creas tu método `create_circle` es un poco confusa y no muy apropiada. Es mejor y más seguro crear una clase que herede de `Canvas` en su lugar. En este caso `MyCanvas` (llamalo como quieras) tiene tu método `create_circle` pero se deja intacta la clase `tkinter.Canvas`. Modificar directamente esta última puede traer consecuencias inesperadas, por ejemplo si otro widget usara la clase original.
- Por último, en el código anterior el radio y el color también son aleatorios. Puedes eliminar el comportamiento cambiando las variables por `radio = 20` y `color = colores[0]`, por ejemplo.

Un ejemplo de como queda:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]